# Image width 100% of the Flex div

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to make an image have a max-width 100% of the parent div, where the parent div is a flex element.

But when I give image 100% width, the image overflows the content!

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/3f8k19g5/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://m.xcite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/u/buy_apple_imac_21.5_inch_all_in_one_desktop__lowest_price_in_ksa_2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="text">This is an iMac</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.image{
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow: 2;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.text{
   background-color: yellow;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: you should apply the style to `img` itself, not the container : https://jsfiddle.net/ya3ya6/qvzacfoj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and updated your code. Run the snippet below.

The image class was being applied to the parent div, I instead moved it to the img tag so the image take 100% of the container div.

```css
.container{
  width: 800px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}

.image{
    background-color: blue;
    flex-grow: 2;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.text{
   background-color: yellow;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!= Feel free to remove the empty div around the image tag if you arent using it ->
  <div>
    <img class="image" src="https://m.xcite.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/u/buy_apple_imac_21.5_inch_all_in_one_desktop__lowest_price_in_ksa_2.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="text">This is an iMac</div>
</div>
```